# How to get property name by one of it's attributes' value using reflection or how to get property info of data property which is currently validating?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, reflection, properties

I want to write custom validation attribute and add additional member names which have validation errors to validation result. The thing is I want to generate member name dynamically based on property name and invalid match property index or key (I want to validate IEnumerables or IDictionaries) like `Names[0]`, `Names[1]`, `Names[key]` etc. For example:

**Model:**

```
public class ModelClass
{
    [ItemMaxLength(10)]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(CategoriesRename), Name = "CategoryNamesFieldName")]
    public IDictionary<string, string> Names { get; set; }
}
```

**Attribute:**

```
public class ItemMaxLengthAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly int _maxLength = int.MaxValue;

    public ItemMaxLengthAttribute(int maxLength)
    {
        _maxLength = maxLength;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ...
        // I can get instance and it's type from validation context
        var instance = validationContext.ObjectInstance; // which is instance of ModelClass
        var instanceType = validationContext.ObjectType; //which is typeof(ModelClass)
        var dispayName = validationContext.DisplayName; //which is value of Display attribute
        ...
    }
}
```

So the main idea is (I don't like it ether) get current property been validated by it's `DysplayName` attribute value (`dispayName`). I'm kind'a stuck here for a while. Maybe is there some other way to get property info of the property which is validating?

**P.S.** I've already tried `MemberName` property, as **Alexandre Rondeau** suggested, but the problem is that `validationContext.MemberName = null` so it can't be used. Also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext.membername.aspx) says that *this property represents an entity member name, not the name of a corresponding data field* and I need **the name of a corresponding data field**.

Comment: 1) In your sample `ModelClass` the `[ItemMaxLength]` is not applied to the `Names` property. Where do you apply the validation attributes? 2) When you say **the name of a corresponding data field** in that example what is that name? Isn't it *Names*?

Comment: @AlexandreRondeau, 1) I've applied attribute to `Names` property (I, possibly, just forgot demonstrate it in example) 2) Yes, it is _Names_... It should be... but `validationContext.MemberName` is `null`. So I have some troubles to get _Names_.

Answer (score 4):

Using that code, both test passes, so the MemberName isn't null.

```
[TestClass]
public class RefectionInValidationTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GivenAModelWithItemMaxAttributeOnFieldName_WhenValidating_ThenModelClassIsValid()
    {
        //Arange
        var validModelClass = new ModelClass();
        var validations = new Collection<ValidationResult>();

        //Act
        var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(validModelClass, new ValidationContext(validModelClass, null, null), validations, true);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(isValid);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GivenAModelWithItemMaxAttributeOnFieldNotName_WhenValidating_ThenModelClassIsInvalid()
    {
        //Arange
        var invalidaModelClass = new InvalidModelClass();
        var validations = new Collection<ValidationResult>();

        //Act
        var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(invalidaModelClass, new ValidationContext(invalidaModelClass, null, null), validations, true);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsFalse(isValid);
    }
}

public class ModelClass
{
    [ItemMaxLength(10)]
    public IDictionary<string, string> Names { get; set; }
}
public class InvalidModelClass
{
    [ItemMaxLength(10)]
    public IDictionary<string, string> NotNames { get; set; }
}

public class ItemMaxLengthAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly int _maxLength = int.MaxValue;

    public ItemMaxLengthAttribute(int maxLength)
    {
        _maxLength = maxLength;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var propretyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(validationContext.MemberName);
        if (propretyInfo.Name == "Names")
            return ValidationResult.Success;

        return new ValidationResult("The property isn't 'Names'");
    }
}
```

Comment: `validationContext.MemberName` is null. So it just throws `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: I've posted my testclass code. Including all classes. Could you run those two tests and tell me if they pass on your system.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `validationContext.MemberName` property.

Example:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
        var userManager = validationContext.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        
        var findingTask = userManager.FindByEmailAsync((string)value);
        findingTask.Wait();

        var user = findingTask.Result;

        return user == null
                ? ValidationResult.Success
                : new ValidationResult("This email already in use", new string[] { validationContext.MemberName });
}
```